# How to process array returned from pgsql?

Tags: php, arrays, json, postgresql

in php i get an array from pgsql:

```
$res = $db
    ->query( "SELECT myarray FROM arrays WHERE array_name=smth" )
    ->fetchRow();
exit (json_encode($res));
```

Type in pgsql is integer[]

But in JS I get JSON with one string "{1,2,3,...,}"
How to get in 'array-way' this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO does not do any kind of type translation, everything is returned as strings. So you will have to parse the string using explode() and build a PHP array yourself.

Answer (score 1):

json_encode Returns a JSON encoded string on success.

Assign the values returned by fetchrow() to a variable and try to print it before json_encode . it will be an array!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the JSON decoded to an array in JavaScript, you can simply use the function eval(). But first you should make sure it is a JSON string.
See more: http://json.org/js.html

Comment: problem is that php get not array() from pgsql but string. I want to get php array and that json_encode will do everything for me without eval

Comment: Why don't you serialize the variable before insert it into the database, and then you just have to reverse it. Check [serialize()](http://pt.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize()](http://pt.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unserialize.php). If you don't want to do that, you'll need to parse them manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$php_array = json_decode( str_replace( 
    array( '[',      ']',      '{', '}' ), 
    array( '\u005B', '\u005D', '[', ']' ), 
    $your_pgsql_array 
) );
```